# Creating a PDF from XML using XSL FO w/ Python

Tags: python, xml, xsl-fo

Could someone point me in the right direction of hopefully a library or code examples, any resources on how to take XML and create a PDF using XSL-FO in Python? If I should have to use an XML renderer, then which XML renderer is recommended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run XSLT programmatically with Python, you want [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

However, if you just need to create a .fo file from a defined XSL/XML pair, you might as well just use `xsltproc`, which is available on any Unix-y system on the command line, including OS X.

Once you have the .fo file, use [Fop](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop) to transform that to PDF.

Comment: the fo file is already there, it is defined, i need to make the xml render into the fo file and create the pdf, thank you for your response

Comment: I am trying to get as much input as possible, so I can make the right decision, searching google just has randomness, I like to hear from those who have actually used these things or are at least fairly familiar, it is much appreciated

Comment: @KacieHouser: You say that the FO file already exists. OK, then you only need to feed it into a FO processor in order to generate a PDF file. [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) is a decent, free FO processor. It is written in Java. There are no FO processors written in Python, but you can of course write a Python program that exercises the [FOP command line interface](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/running.html#fop-script).

Comment: @mzjn I realized this after I posted. Thank you guys so much for the input

Comment: As an update this is a link for Pypfop a python processor for FOP 

https://pypfop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [XHTML2PDF](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/). It's very easy to use. Create your XHTML template. Use Jinja2 (or similar) to fill in the template. Convert to PDF.

Comment: I have no choice in the technologies, the xsl-fo file is ready and the xml is ready, my task is to create a pdf using the xml and xsl file in Python. Stuck. Like. Chuck.

Comment: XHTML is XML.  I don't get the distinction.  If you have to use XSL-FO, then you simply run the Java executable.

Comment: I was referring to the suggestion of using Jinja, I am checking it out though...looking for this Java executable you are talking about.