# xml + xslfo to PDF python

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

Is there a simple way to get a PDF from a xml with an xsl-fo?
I would like to do it in python.
I know how to do an html from an xml&xsl, but I haven't find a code example to get a PDF.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a PDF from XML using XSL FO w/ Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573215/creating-a-pdf-from-xml-using-xsl-fo-w-python)

Answer (score 1):

XSL FO requires a formatting engine to create print output like PDF from XSL FO input. Freely available one is Apache FOP. There are several other commercial products also. I know of no XSL FO engines written in Python though some have Python interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

The [rinohtype](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype#readme) Python library can help you create a PDF from a structured document such as XML. You will need to write a frontend for your XML format to transform your document to a rinohtype document tree.

Rinohtype is not based on XSL-FO, but its CSS-like style sheets should allow for much easier styling of the PDF output.

(Full disclosure: I am the author of rinohtype)